# What is Facebook Web Games URL

Tags: facebook, https, web-hosting

What is **Facebook Web Games URL** in `developers.facebook.com -> settings->  Basic-> Facebook Web Games-> Facebook Web Games URL (https) ?`

Why do I need it?

Why I must use only **`https`**?

Answer (score 1):

> What is Facebook Web Games URL?

It is the URL of the place where you host your game. `htts://www.yourdomain.com/yourgame`.

> Why do I need it?

Because that is what Facebook shows in an iframe on `apps.facebook.com/yournamespace`

> Why I must use only https?

Because browsers usually don´t show iframe content with http in a parent page that runs with https - apps.facebook.com runs with https.

---

If you don´t know what it´s for, you can actually just ignore it ;)